# Why is numpy.random.choice modifying my data?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

**Task**: use numpy.random.choice to sample from [0,512] randomly where the numbers are expressed in bytes array.

**Problem**: numpy casts 512 to 2.

**Code Example**:

```
import numpy
a = (512).to_bytes(4, 'big')
b = (0).to_bytes(4, 'big')
print(int.from_bytes(numpy.random.choice([a,b]), 'big'))
```

**Expected output**: `0` or `512`

**Actual output**: `0` or `2`

However, if `numpy.random.choice` is replaced by the built-in `random`, this will not happen.

Comment: I think this is because how numpy handles byte arrays by default. If you change to 'little' instead of 'big' it will work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`np.random.choice` first converts the input list to an array and Numpy interprets the datatype of `a` and `b` as null terminated bytes (raw strings) and removes the trailing zero when storing them.

```
# dtype `|S4` means zero terminated bytes of length 4 with byte order not applicable.                                                       
np.array([a, b])
>> array([b'\x00\x00\x02', b''], dtype='|S4')
```

So `np.random.choice` will operate on this array and it will return one of `b'\x00\x00\x02'` or `b''` which will be interpreted as 2 or 0 with big-endian byte order by Python.

If you want to sample from an array of raw bytes with Numpy, you have to create the array from a byte buffer instead of a list of bytes:

```
# [512, 0] as big-endian int32
buffer = bytearray([0,0,2,0, 0,0,0,0])
# '>i4' means big-endian int32
array = np.ndarray(shape=(2,), dtype='>i4', buffer=buffer)
>> array([512,   0], dtype=int32)
np.random.choice(array)
>> 0 or 512
```

Comment: Note that this behavior has caused problems : [See issue on numpy github](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/3878).